# Optimization voltage divider measurement

Tags: voltage-divider, voltage-measurement, optimization

How to design a voltage divider to optimize the measurement error?

Intuitively I would take the same ratio $$\frac{load}{divider} = \frac{divider}{measurement}$$
As follow: the voltage is roughly divided by 5. The divider induces 1% error on the load, and the measurement 1% error on the divider.

Is it a good practice?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fK8VMq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You can use a voltage follower. Adding a voltage follower to the voltage divider circuit isolates the load impedance (Rmeasurement) so that VOUT is dependent upon R1 and R2, not Rmeasurement.

Comment: yeah sure, but I want to make it simple, I have 32 inputs in parallel and do not want to implement 32 voltage followers :) so I want to optimize my voltage divider

Comment: What makes you say that the "divider introduces 1% error on the load"? The voltage across the load and across the divider must be identical (for an ideal voltage source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is about what I was looking for:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva450a/slva450a.pdf

[image]